# grails internationalization: a strange behaviour

Tags: grails, internationalization

I'm using grails for my project and I'm facing a little trouble.
I have an Internationalization system and I use messages.properties files to list all strings that needs to be internationalized.
I've created one as follows:

```
<g:message code='logged.in.as'/>
```

in my messages.properties file I have the following:

```
logged.in.as=Logged in as\:
```

but, when I load the browser, I see the following

```
logged.in.as
```

Why this strange behaviour?Notice that I use the `<g:message>` tag for a lot of other strings and everything works well...

Comment: Try changing to text to not include \ and : ?

Comment: This is not a problem. Restart the app. Make sure the entry is **actually** present in `messages.properties` instead of any other i18n property file.

Comment: What version of Grails?

Comment: If after restarting works well, your version of grails 2.2.1 :)

Comment: Afer two restarts...it magically works!